# What is the definition of 'live days' in experimental particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology

Interestingly, googling the term does not throw up results beyond the papers I originally found it in - related to dark matter detectors like XENON-100. I assume it's the live time of the experiment (which I'm also not sure of the definition for - the amount of time it was taking data, I think?), converted into days. Is that correct? If anyone could confirm this and give a complete definition, or point me in the direction of resources defining it, I'd be very grateful.

Here's where I originally came across the term: [XENON100](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06154)

Comment: Can you give a reference?

Comment: @pfnuesel Added to the question. It appears in several other papers by the collaboration too.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, live days means the amount of time the experiment was taking data, and all the systems were running correctly, etc.

Comment: Yep. And it is a specific unit of the more general 'live time'.